# Select all json objects that have array != empty in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, if-statement, fetch

I have a problem in returning the right data via javascript when fetching a file.json.
The original has too many lines of code, so I will write a shorter example to make it clearer.

I have my data.json file that looks something like this: 
**data.json**

```
{ 
  "01": {
     "id" : "01",
     "title" : "example1",
     "size" : "100",
     "pictures" : []
  },
  "02": {
     "id" : "02",
     "title" : "example2",
     "size" : "0",
     "pictures" : []
  },
  "03": {
     "id" : "03",
     "title" : "example3",
     "size" : "300",
     "pictures" : [
       { "pic_name1" : "example_pic1", "source" : "http://example.pic/1234" },
       { "pic_name2" : "example_pic2", "source" : "http://example.pic/4321" },
     ]
  },
  
}
```

My fetch works just fine, I can print out the data I want. For example, I don't want to get the objects that have "size" = "0" and that works. What does not work is the second condition: I want to get ONLY the objects that have some pictures (in other words, objects where pictures !== []) and I want the firsst pic in every object.

This is the part of my function that does that:

**main.js**

```
getData().then(data => {
    for (const key in data) {
      if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (data[key].size !== "0" && data[key].pictures !== []  ) {  
             div.innerText = data[key].size;                        // This prints the right data in DOM
             img.src = data[key].pictures[0].source                 // This gives an error
        }
      }
   });
```

The error I get in the inspector is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined
> at (index):94

!!!
This code works if I hard code the id of the object instead of writing [key], like this:

```
img.src = data[01].picture[0].source           //  This is return the picture of the selected object
```

But of course, I need to get the right pic for each object.
Any idea how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Check `length` of `pictures` like `data[key].pictures.length > 0` instead of `data[key].pictures !== []`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check length of pictures like `data[key].pictures.length > 0` instead of `data[key].pictures !== []`

```js
let data = { 
  "01": {
     "id" : "01",
     "title" : "example1",
     "size" : "100",
     "pictures" : []
  },
  "02": {
     "id" : "02",
     "title" : "example2",
     "size" : "0",
     "pictures" : []
  },
  "03": {
     "id" : "03",
     "title" : "example3",
     "size" : "300",
     "pictures" : [
       { "pic_name1" : "example_pic1", "source" : "http://example.pic/1234" },
       { "pic_name2" : "example_pic2", "source" : "http://example.pic/4321" },
     ]
  },
  
}

for (const key in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    if (data[key].size !== "0" && data[key].pictures.length>0){ 
        console.log(data[key].size);                     
        console.log(data[key].pictures[0].source);
    }
  }
}
```